# How to use existing signing key for signing capacitor android app, that was used to sign the ionic cordova android app?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, capacitor

I had an ionic cordova App, that i migrated to capacitor recently. Now i want to publish my capacitor app with new version but same app package id as cordova app. I have my app signing key named myapp.keystore file and it's key generation password.I used this signing key to update many versions of my cordova app successfully.Now i have a capacitor app. My question is how can i use my signing key in android studio to sign the capacitor app code. What should i enter in android studio for -

1. Key store password
2. Key Alias and
3. Key password, as shown in picture
   [image]

I tried using my signing key's key generation password for Keystore password and Key password. I used the keystore filename (myapp) as Key alias and it generated the bundle successfully. But when i uploaded it to the google play console it gave me the error -

`Your android app bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct key...`

Comment: you have to click the "choose existing" and select the file you are already using

Comment: Thank you for replying but you can see in picture i already chose the file. Did you read the question ?

Comment: I have read it and I don't read anywhere that you have chosen the existing file, you only say that you are using the same password and name